# how to install an extension from chrome web store using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-store

I am trying to automate an action in this website, https://chocolia.eu/voter but i get blocked by cloudflare, it freezes the website and when i refresh it here is what it does : [image]

i can use undetected chrome driver for this situation and it works with it but i need an extension for this to work and undetected chrome driver is not compatible with extensions so i want to install it from chrome webstore but you have to confirm the installation of the extension and it is not a javascript alert as i tried driver.switch_to.alert .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be undetected but U.C can't install extension, you should read the solution given by colossatr0n in this thread : [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)
Here is a partial copy of the response, the idee is to replace the **cdc_** in chromedriver.exe to not be detected :

> The bot detection scripts usually look anything containing word "selenium" / "webdriver" in any of the variables (on window object), and also document variables called **$cdc_** and **$wdc_**.
> This is the function I modified in chromedriver:
> **File call_function.js:**

```
function getPageCache(opt_doc) {
  var doc = opt_doc || document;
  //var key = '$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_';
  var key = 'randomblabla_';
  if (!(key in doc))
    doc[key] = new Cache();
  return doc[key];
}
```

> (Note the comment. All I did I turned **$cdc_** to **randomblabla_**.)

And finally i recommande you to replace **$cdc_** by **xxxx** (same number of charactere) and modify it in HexEditor.
( Moi aussi j'ai joué à chocolia.Mc avant add : l !'Magics#3537 )